# Transform a permutation from cycle notation to standard form

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations, permutation-cycles

A permutation of a set  is a bijection (one-to-one and onto) : → .

the object can viewed as:

$\sigma =$

$$
    \begin{matrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
    3 & 1 & 4 & 2 & 5 \\
    \end{matrix}
$$

Now given the following permutation in cycle notation, I want to convert it to standard form as above.

consider the cycle: $(1,2)(3,5)(4,1,3)$ Now if it didn't have the repeats of $(1,3)$ I would be able to write it out as above

Comment: is your convention to apply the cycle on the right or on the left first?

Comment: we go from right to left

Comment: So... $1\mapsto 3$ from the right cycle, then immediately after it continues  with $3\mapsto 5$ from the middle cycle then the left cycle doesn't change it any further... so we have that altogether $1\mapsto 5$.  Meanwhile in the case of starting with $2$, the right cycle doesn't change it, neither does the middle cycle, and the left cycle will change it from $2$ to $1$, so altogether $2\mapsto 1$.  So, your permutation begins as $\begin{pmatrix}1&2&3&4&5\\5&1&\dots\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: Reworded, if you want to think of permutations as functions (*which they are, remember*) and we want to see how the composition of permutations acts on a specific element, $(\rho \sigma\pi)[1] = \rho[\sigma[\pi[1]]]$.  Here with $\rho = (1,2)$ and $\sigma = (3,5)$ and $\pi=(4,1,3)$, we have $(\rho\sigma\pi)[1]=\rho[\sigma[\pi[1]]] = \rho[\sigma[3]]=\rho[5]=5$

Comment: yes we have briefly looked at them as functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you go from right to left,

$(1,2)(3,5)(4,1,3)$ maps $1\mapsto3\mapsto5$, $2\mapsto1$, $3\mapsto4$, $4\mapsto1\mapsto2$, and $5\mapsto3$,

so it's
$\pmatrix {1&2&3&4&5\\5&1&4&2&3}.$